# Force webview to open urls inside application - android app

Tags: android

How to force `WebView` to open all the urls inside the application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to override the `WebViewClient` for your `WebView`.

[See here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) for the details: it's pretty straight forward.

Notice Step 6 in particular.

> To open links clicked by the user, simply provide a `WebViewClient` for
>   your `WebView`, using `setWebViewClient()`. For example:
>
> ```
> WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
> myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
> ```
>
> That's it. Now all links the user clicks load in your `WebView`.